# Why is playorm not building?

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception, playorm

Here is my process to a stopping point:

Starting with making the extensions in WinExplorer visible, I deciphered what file is in fact the .bat file, clicking that file, opened a cmd prompt and informed that the "JAVA_HOME environment variable wasn't set correctly."

So, preceded to set the environment to
C:\Program Files\Java\Playorm\deanhiller-playorm-6558bf1
Reattempted the .bat file and command took approx. 4 sec to compile

In eclipse, I started a "new project" ,
clicked "Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile"
and choose the build.xml file from the "bldfiles" folder.
the "projectExplorer" window in Eclipse began to populate with the javasrc, src, and multiple.jar files.
0 errors, 5 warnings, and 4 others (as shown in screenshot)

As a newbie, No posting pics, [click here](https://ws.elance.com/php/files/main/download.php?crypted=Y3R4JTNEcG1iJTI2ZmlkJTNENTMxMjE1ODElMjZyaWQlM0QtMSUyNnBpZCUzRDMzMjc2NDQ2) to see screenshot!

Next, right click on the package com.alvazan.test
and choose Run As -> Junit Test, resulting in:
11/55 runs, 15 errors, and 0 failures. (as shown in screenshot)

Once again, as a newbie, No posting pics, so [click here](https://ws.elance.com/php/files/main/download.php?crypted=Y3R4JTNEcG1iJTI2ZmlkJTNENTMxMjIyMjQlMjZyaWQlM0QtMSUyNnBpZCUzRDMzMjc2NDQ2) to see screenshot!

The "Run-Time Exception" goes as follows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    C:\Program%20Files\Java\Playorm\deanhiller-playorm-6558bf1\output\classes 
    (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: I can't see those images.  Please include error messages as text.

Comment: Better provide us source code with examples.

Comment: *"Why is playorm not building?"*  I'd say it is due to the `FileNotFoundException`.  Should I enter that as an answer?  Note that SO is best for specific answers to specific questions, and most of what you posted was irrelevant to the final error. +1 for thinking to copy/paste it, BTW.  :)

Comment: his question is fine and he is correct, playorm does not build in paths with spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you ran into a bug in playOrm(you may want to tag the question as playorm as well as we only are subscribed to questions tagged playorm).  Move the project to a path without spaces as a workaround

EDIT: Bug is now fixed in playOrm and will be merged to the master branch within the week.